# Parse push notifications on iOS 8 using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I need to make application which use parse's push notifications. I was using this https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_push/ios/existing and this https://gist.github.com/sawapi/a7cee65e4ad95578044d.

Code was compiled properly and I get

> Sorry, there was an error sending the push

on the first site. First tutorial from parse.com works perfectly. I have add *.p12 file to parse but certificate was made by my mail not ios developer mail.

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        Parse.setApplicationId(MY_APP_ID,
            clientKey: MY_APP_KEY)
        PFUser.enableAutomaticUser()

        if application.respondsToSelector("isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications")
        {
            // iOS 8 Notifications
            //application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: (.Badge | .Sound | .Alert), categories: nil));
            var types: UIUserNotificationType = UIUserNotificationType.Badge |
                UIUserNotificationType.Alert |
                UIUserNotificationType.Sound

            var settings: UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings( forTypes: types, categories: nil )

            application.registerUserNotificationSettings( settings )
            application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

            return true
        }
        else
        {
            // iOS < 8 Notifications
            application.registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(.Badge | .Sound | .Alert)
        }

        var defaultACL = PFACL()
        // If you would like all objects to be private by default, remove this line.
        defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true)
        PFACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, withAccessForCurrentUser: true)

        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }
    func application(application: UIApplication!, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData! ) {
        var currentInstallation: PFInstallation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
        currentInstallation.setDeviceTokenFromData(deviceToken)
        currentInstallation.save()

        println("got device id! \(deviceToken)")
    }
    func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
        PFPush.handlePush(userInfo)
    }
}
```

Comment: `registerUserNotificationSettings` not `isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications` in if application.respondsToSelector("isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications")

Comment: but if you get error on the site... check again the certificate... on the Parse.com is something wrong...

Comment: I will try to make certificate for my iOS development mail

Comment: download this project... set up your key (check in a real device).. and check if you get the notifications https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_push/ios/new

Comment: so i need to make any changes with code or just check certificate? Where can i send notyfications?

Comment: Hmmm, just a question, are you trying to recieve notification on the simulator, or on a device? The simulator doesn't support this function, only push are able from it.

Comment: thanks for sharing your app ID and secret key publicly.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution :

```
import UIKit
import Parse




@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {



        // REGISTER FOR PUSH NOTIFICATIONS
        let notifTypes:UIUserNotificationType  = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: notifTypes, categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0




return true
}


// MARK: - DELEGATES FOR PUSH NOTIFICATIONS
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    let installation = PFInstallation.current()
    installation?.setDeviceTokenFrom(deviceToken)
    installation?.saveInBackground(block: { (succ, error) in
        if error == nil {
            print("DEVICE TOKEN REGISTERED!")
        } else {
            print("\(error!.localizedDescription)")
        }
    })
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
    print("application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: %@", error)
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) {
    print("\(userInfo)")

    // PFPush.handle(userInfo)
    if application.applicationState == .inactive {
        PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithRemoteNotificationPayload(inBackground: userInfo, block: nil)
    }
}





func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {

        let installation = PFInstallation.current()
        print("BADGE: \(installation!.badge)")
        if installation?.badge != 0 {
            installation?.badge = 0
            installation?.saveInBackground(block: { (succ, error) in
                if error == nil {
                    print("Badge reset to 0")
                } else {
                    print("\(error!.localizedDescription)")
            }})
        }
}
```